Append a node to a XML struktur as first child
I am trying to a add a created structure to an existing XML which I read in with XMLSlurper. With xml.append() it works, but it will be put at the end. How to insert at a specific position? It should be insert as first child of: multimap:Message1
Source Message.
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://example.com">
<multimap:Message1>
    <ns1:CostCenter xmlns:ns1="urn:example-com">
        <item>
            <POSID>123</POSID>
            <POSID_FORMATED>P.12.3</POSID_FORMATED>
            <YYBEZ>Apple</YYBEZ>
        </item>
        <item>
            <POSID>456</POSID>
            <POSID_FORMATED>P.45.6</POSID_FORMATED>
            <YYBEZ>Banana</YYBEZ>
        </item>
    </ns1:CostCenter>
    <ns0:CostCenter xmlns:ns0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
        <item>
            <KOSTL>0815</KOSTL>
            <LTEXT_DE>Supermarket</LTEXT_DE>
        </item>
        <item>
            <KOSTL>6666</KOSTL>
            <LTEXT_DE>Online Shop</LTEXT_DE>
        </item>
    </ns0:CostCenter>
</multimap:Message1>

</multimap:Messages>
My code:
def Message processData() {
def countries = ["DE",SP","IT"]
def countriesCode = ["Germany",Spain","Italy"]

def countryList = new Node(null, "CountryList")

countries.eachWithIndex { country, index ->
    def part = countryList.appendNode("part")
    part.appendNode("CountryCode", countriesCode[index]?.trim())
    part.appendNode("Country", country?.trim())
}

// with xml.append(countryList)  he added it at the end of my input XML
// with the following he will add it after multimap:Messages tag
// but I could not put it under multimap:Message1
xml.children().add(1,countryList)

def updatedXml = XmlUtil.serialize(xml)

}
I tried a lot like

giving the path  xml.Message1.children().add(1,countryList)
replaceBody() function
searching the node to append: def msg1Node = xml.'multimap:Messge1'.first() and then append there

Not sure if the prefix makes trouble or if there is another issue, but how to append my structure as first child of multimap:Message1 ?
Thanks :-)

show please what xml parser you are using

also provide the correct xml and expected result
